# Can Java Handle ADO Errors

Tags: java, asp.net

I'm wondering if it's possible to use ADO Errors in Java.

I'm looking at some ASP code that uses ADO for Errors, I believe I've converted it to JAVA.

Is it possible to even do or is there better error handling in Java?

I'm familiar with using a try catch block, but I'm not sure how to incorporate all the errors into one.

There are about 10 different errors, I cut them out for this question and just left a few errors for this question

**Snippet of ASP Code:**

```
If Err.number <> 0 Then
    Response.Write("<!-- ADO Errors Begin -->" & vbCrLf)
        For each objError in con_duns_sdo2.Errors
            Response.Write("<!-- ADO Error.Number = " & objError.Number & "-->" & vbCrLf)
            Response.Write("<!-- ADO Error.Description = " & objError.Description & "-->" & vbCrLf)
    Next
            Response.Write("<!-- ADO Errors End -->" & vbCrLf)
            Response.Write("<!-- VBScript Errors Begin -->" & vbCrLf)
```

**Snippet of Java that I'm trying to convert:**

```
for (objError : con_currency_sdo) {
                    if (con_currency_sdo.Errors == "true") {
                         System.out.println("ADO Error.Number" + objError.Number + "\r\n");
                         System.out.println("ADO Error.Description" + objError.Description + "\r\n");

                    }else{
                         System.out.println("ADO Errors End" + "\r\n");
                         System.out.println("VBScript Errors Begin" + "\r\n");
                    }
               }
```

Comment: in java you would use a `try/catch` block and catch any exceptions your code may throw. And you would not usually use ADO, but rather a JDBC driver for the database you are trying to connect to. JDBC is very common and a lot of other languages wrap JDBC since it's so easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), *ADO.NET is a set of classes that expose data access services for .NET Framework programmers. ADO.NET provides a rich set of components for creating distributed, data-sharing applications. It is an integral part of the .NET Framework, providing access to relational, XML, and application data. ADO.NET supports a variety of development needs, including the creation of front-end database clients and middle-tier business objects used by applications, tools, languages, or Internet browsers.*

Given that, the answer is no. Java does not and cannot natively integrate with any .NET Framework (there are third-party commercial libraries that enable it, but they're typically non-trivial to work with). Instead Java uses JDBC to perform database operations in a vendor neutral cross-platform way.